# Confused by local variables and methods in Perl

Tags: perl

I've got the following **Perl** code:

```
my $wantedips;

# loop through the interfaces
foreach (@$interfaces) {

  # local variable called $vlan
  my $vlan = $_->{vlan};

  # local variable called $cidr
  my $cidr = $_->{ip} ."/".$nnm->bits();

  # I dont understand this next bit.
  # As a rubyist, it looks like a method called $cidr is being called on $wantedips 
  # But $cidr is already defined as a local variable.
  # Why the spooky syntax? Why is $cidr passed as a method to $wantedips?
  # what does ->{} do in PERL? Is it some kind of hash syntax?
  $wantedips->{$cidr} = $vlan;


  # break if condition true
  next if ($ips->{$cidr} == $vlan);

  # etc
}
```

The part I don't get is in my comments. Why is $cidr passed to $wantedips, when both are clearly defined as local variables? I'm a rubyist and this is really confusing. I can only guess that `$xyz->{$abc}="hello"` creates a hash of some sort like so:

```
$xyz => {        
  $abc => "hello"
}
```

I'm new to **Perl** as you can probably tell.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html — "Perl" is the name of the language. Only the "P" is capitalized. The name of the interpreter (the program which runs the Perl script) is "perl" with a lowercase "p".

You may or may not choose to follow this usage. But never write "PERL", because perl is not an acronym.

Comment: Thanks I will stop calling it PERL immediately.

Comment: @Quentin: I don't understand the persistence of `PERL`. I don't think I have ever seen `RUBY`, `PYTHON` or `JAVASCRIPT`. Perhaps people think it's an acronym if it isn't an English word

Comment: People read about it standing for "Practical Extraction and Reporting Language" and assume that it's an acronym. No amount of explaining that it's actually a backronym seems to fix that :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> #I dont understand this next bit.
> $wantedips->{$cidr} = $vlan;
> ```

`$wantedips` is a scalar, specifically it is a hashref (a reference to a hash).

The arrow gets something from inside the reference.

`{"keyname"}` is how to access a particular key in a hash.

`->{"keyname"}` is how you access a particular key in a hash ref

`$cidr` is also a scalar, in this case it is a string.

`->{$cidr}` accesses a key from a hash ref when the key name is stored in a string.

So to put it all together:

`$wantedips->{$cidr} = $vlan;` means "Assign the value of `$vlan` to the key described by the string stored in `$cidr` on the hash referenced by `$wantedips`.

---

> I can only guess that $xyz->{$abc}="hello" creates a hash of some sort
>   like.

Let's break this down to a step by step example that strips out the loops and other bits not directly associated with the code in question.

```
# Create a hash
my %hash; 

# Make it a hashref
my $xyz = \%hash;

# (Those two steps could be done as: my $xyz = {})

# Create a string
my $abc = "Hello";

# Use them together
$xyz->{$abc} = "world";

# Look at the result:
use Data::Dump;
Data::Dump::ddx($xyz);

# Result: { Hello => "world" }
```

Comment: Ahh this makes sense, we have the same ideas in Ruby. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @marflar, yes Ruby is very influenced by Perl. (Matz used Perl a lot before creating Ruby.) If you strip out the `;`, change the meanings of a few sigils, and squint the right way, Perl looks very like Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you are comfortable with

```
my $vlan = $_->{vlan}
```

but then

```
$wantedips->{$cidr} = $vlan
```

gives you trouble? Both use the same syntax to access hash elements using a hash reference.

The *indirection operator* `->` is used to apply keys, indices, or parameters to a *reference* value, so you access elements of a hash by its reference with

```
$href->{vlan}
```

elements of an array by its reference with

```
$aref->[42]
```

and call a code reference with

```
$cref->(1, 2, 3)
```

As a convenience, and to make code cleaner, you can remove the indirection operator from the sequences `]->[` and `}->{` (and any mixture of brackets and braces). So if you have a nested data structure you can write

```
my $name = $system->{$ip_address}{name}[2]
```

instead of

```
my $name = $system->{$ip_address}->{name}->[2]
```